# Securing a web service

Tags: web-services, security, wif

We build web services that are for consumption by known third-parties.

We tend to implement very basic security that involves:

- A known token ID which we communicate to both parties
- Restrict access to known subset of IP addresses
- Secure the transport layer via SSL

I'm not comfortable with this, but implementing Federated Security (using WIF/ADFS 2) is VERY complex!  How can I justify using this tech - what is fundamentally wrong with the above approach?

I realise that the web service (which might expose sensitive data) is now only as secure as the token, but so would a username/password combo.

Thanks
Duncan

Comment: no other better approach I can say

Comment: Basically you could setup your own certificate authority and issue certificates to the known parties. If you create a certificate for your server, you can have mutual authentication almost for free.

Comment: Why do you think implementing Federated Security (using WIF/ADFS 2) is VERY complex?

Comment: Because to someone who hasn't dealt with it before it looks that way!  Having said that I've caught up on some tutorials and it seems that there are Claims Aware templates for WCF services that can be downloaded and these set up the WS-Federation protocols in the config almost automatically.  Using fedutil I can also establish the relationship between the STS server and my web service.  But certainly a lot more complex than my scenario!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To improve or replace the common token i would use some client/server certificate authentification. You will use SSL anyway and client certificate gives some more features